# Keys Support in JSON file of Openai Function Calling

Tags: openai-api, large-language-model, chatgpt-api

recently I found how powerful is the function calling in ChatGPT. But I don't see any specific official documents for the json file.
An example json file like:

```
functions = [
    {
        "name": "get_order_details",
        "description": "Retrieves the details of an order given its order ID.",
        "parameters": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "order_id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "The unique identifier of the order.",
                }
            },
            "required": ["order_id"],
        },
    }
]
```

I want to ask that except the keys like `"name"`, `"description"`, `"parameters"`, any other keys support in this json file? By the way, if I want to define a key like "default", how can I do? Thanks for any answers.